# Unknown errors with Datagram Packets and Sockets - Java Networking

Tags: java, networking

Hey, I've been playing around with the Datagram classes and I just can't figure out why my "server" won't receive packets from the "client".

I've tested it with the server and client both running on my own PC at once and it works perfectly, but if I try to move the server over to another PC, it...doesnt.

Now I know I must be doing something wrong with sockets/addresses/ports bleh...I haven't worked with networking before so I don't know much.

Here's the server code:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private boolean needsToRun;
    private DatagramSocket socket;

    public ServerThread() {
        super();
        needsToRun = true;
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(4446);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(needsToRun) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[265];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);
            try {
                socket.receive(packet);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String data = new String(packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength());
            if(data != null)
                System.out.println(data);
        }
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

You'll see some unused imports, but I just stripped down the code to make it basic (most of it came from what I actually want the server to do with the data once it is received, but I've got that part working).

Here's the client code:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException, IOException {

            // get a datagram socket
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

            // send request
        String testInfo = "Hi";
        byte[] buf = testInfo.getBytes();

        /*This could possible be a point at which the code won't work.
         *to get the bytes of the IP address of the computer I'm trying to run the server 
         *on I just did
         * byte[] address = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress();
         * on the computer I was running the server on. I'm 95% sure that the IP addresses 
         * match.
         */
        byte[] inet = {-64,-88,1,5};
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(inet);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 4446);
        try {
            socket.send(packet);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Obvious parts of the code, I've checked, like the port and address (see in-code comment).

So what I'm really looking for is, if you don't see why the code wouldnt be working, then could you tell me some things that may go wrong with the ports and whatnot (port might be closed, etc. (except I'm also fairly certain the port is open)).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking the packets?  Have you tried disabling the firewalls on each computer?

Answer (score 1):

> I've tested it with the server and client both running on my own PC at once and it works perfectly, but if I try to move the server over to another PC, it...doesnt.

I expect that this some kind of network or firewall issue, rather than an issue with your Java client and server applications.  (The evidence that they can talk when run on the same machine points that way ...)

Check these things:

- Check that the client can resolve the server's IP address; e.g. try pinging it or connecting to it on some other port that is known to be supported by the server.
- Check that the software firewalls on client and server machines allow UDP traffic on port 4446.
- If there is a bridge and/or router between the two machines, check that it is not blocking UDP traffic on port 4446.

Comment: I recently had to do this and ran into trouble with multiple network interfaces (some virtual).  So also check that the IPs you're using are the right ones for the network you're using.  Also, install Wireshark.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks for the response. I am able to successfully ping the IP address that I'm trying to connect to. I went into Windows Firewall on the server computer and added a UDP traffic exception for port 4446. I wasn't quite sure what you meant by the third suggestion, if you could elaborate it would be great. Also, @Michael, like Stephen's third suggestion I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm quite new to networking so sorry if I'm coming off a bit slow. And as for Wireshark, I don't know how I'd be able to successfully use that. It seems like all it could tell me is if the server PC is

Comment: actually receiving the packet, which if it was, would ?be noticed in the server application?

Comment: Oh, and I didnt actually clarify (@Stephen) it still doesn't seem to be working. I've played around with the isReachable(timeout) method, and when running it from the client, it always returns false.

Comment: If the client and server machines are not on the same physical piece of ethernet wire, there is some other piece of networking hardware connecting them.  Or maybe multiple bits of hardware.  Any one of those bits of hardware could in theory be configured to block UDP packets on port 4446.

Comment: So what are the usual suspects that could be filtering out traffic from certain ports? Or is that a really vague question?

Comment: Ok so I looked into this with a program called "CurrPorts". Here is what it found when my application was running (http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/1513/portstate.jpg). I don't know if you're faimiliar with the program or not, but under the column "State", most ports say "Established", "Listening", or "Closed Wait", while the port I'm trying to use has nothing listed. Any idea on why that would be? Do I need to declare something in my code, or is it still the hardware that's the issue?

Comment: 1) Yes that's a really vague question.  I suggest that you talk to your local networking folks.  2) Established / Listening / Closed Wait states are all for TCP.  They don't apply to UDP.